# WSO2 Identity Server userAdmin Web Service Failed to Re-use

Tags: wso2, cxf, jax-ws, wso2-identity-server

My WSO2 Identity Server version is 4.0.0 final. I have turned on admin service.

Here are the two requests.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mgt:listUsers>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mgt:filter>*</mgt:filter>
      </mgt:listUsers>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mgt:getAllRolesNames/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If i call them separately in Test Case, it is okay. If i call listUsers first, and then getAllRolesNames (In SOAPUI, call listUser first, then change the Envelope to getAllRolesName one), it shows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns:UserAdminUserAdminException xmlns:ns="http://mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org">
               <UserAdminException xsi:type="ax2566:UserAdminException" xmlns="http://mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:ax2566="http://common.mgt.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                  <ax2566:errorMessage xsi:nil="true"/>
               </UserAdminException>
            </ns:UserAdminUserAdminException>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Does it mean there are some bug inside server side implementation ?

I tested them in SOAPUI. The login session is not expired, i can still use it for querying. Does it mean i have to create ws client bean using request scope instead of session scope?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you turn on the AdminService?

Comment: @AdrianMitev Hi, set HideAdminServiceWSDLs to false in wso2is-4.0.0\repository\conf\carbon.xml

Comment: Thank you! I did that and I'm currently accessing the service through the java stubs.

Comment: could you try to reproduce the problem? Call listUsers first, and then getAllRolesNames, from the same userAdmin stub object ?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry for the late answer. I have tried to call these two methods for the same stub object and it works perfectly.